# How to insert a basic HTML code for print some string into Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, hello.js

I would like to print a single "Hello World" line in HTML into Angularjs. Is that possible?
Please Help!

Comment: you mean insert HTML like `<p>Hello World</p>`?

Comment: Could you please explain clearly what is needed??

Comment: Yes, i would like to print a single Hello World @Rebornix

Comment: You want to insert actual html code via angular into your HTML that has "Hello World" in it, or do you want to just use angular to print "Hello World" from an angular variable in your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

One of these ways

```
<div ng-controller="myController">

    <p>{{ message }}</p>

    <div class="container"></div>

</div>

<script>
    app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        //angular variable to print
        $scope.message = "Hello World";

        //regular javascript
        var div = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
        div[0].innerHTML = $scope.message;

        //jQuery
        $(".container").html($scope.message);

    }]);
</script>
```

Comment: Is not working @JeremyJackson look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5jycryrc/3/

Comment: I assumed you knew how to initiate the app and use the example. Here's a working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/st84ow6m/1/